# aggregate all columns and shapiro.test

Tags: aggregate

I would like to aggregate all my columns (here only two but i have 25 in reality) by my first column which contains different groups and in addition i would like to use a shapiro.test as FUN argument.
 Here is y data with my modalities and 2 variables with values for each modality (I did n=10-9 replicates for this experience).

structure(list(moda = structure(c(20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L), .Label = c("ACN1", "ACN2", 
"BA", "BM", "BS1", "BS2", "CN", "EK5", "HW1", "HW2", "HW3", "L27", 
"L5K", "LC", "M2K", "M630", "PB1", "PB2", "PB3", "PG", "RMB", 
"RMC", "RMM"), class = "factor"), epicotyle = c(1.5, 1.5, 2, 
1, 1.5, 1.2, 1, 2.4, 1.3, 1.4, 1.7, 2, 1.8, 2.3, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 
1.5, 2, 1.3, 1.5, 1.8, 1.3, 1.8, 1.7, 1.5, 2.3, 1.8, 2.2, 1.5, 
1.5, 1.5, 1.3, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.8, 1.5, 2.1, 1.8, 1.3, 2, 
1.5, 2, 3.5, 1.5, 1.7, 1.7, 2, 1.7, 2, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 2, 2, 1.5, 
2, 1.5, 1.8, 1, 2, 3, 1.6, 1.5, 1.5, 1.3, 1.5, 1.5, 1.2, 1.5, 
1.5, 1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 1.1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.7, 1.8, 
1.5, 1.3, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 1.2, 1.4, 1, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 1.2, 1.5, 
2, 2.3, 2.1, 2, 2.4, 1.5, 1.7, 1.4, 2.4, 1, 1, 2, 1.5, 1.2, 2.4, 
1.2, 1, 0.8, 1.8, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.1, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5, 1.3, 1.5, 
3, 2.6, 1.5, 2.2, 1.9, 1.5, 1.4, 1.4, 2.5, 2.1, 2, 1.5, 2, 2, 
2, 1.5, 2.1, 2, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 3, 3, 3.5, 3.5, 3, 2, 2.5, 3.5, 
1, 1.2, 1.5, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.4, 1.5, 2, 3, 1.7, 
3, 2.5, 2, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 1.4, 1.2, 
1.7, 2.1, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 1.4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2.5, 3, 3, 
1.7, 3, 1.8, 2, 1.8, 2.2, 2.3, 1.5, 2, 1.8, 1.8, 1.3, 2, 1.8, 
1.8, 2, 1.8, 1.5, 1.7, 2, 1.4, 1.5, 1.7, 1.5), hypocotyle = c(3.8, 
4, 7, 5, 6, 4, 5.4, 3.5, 3.6, 5, 5, 7, 2.5, 6.5, 5.4, 5, 6, 5.7, 
7, 5.5, 5.7, 5.5, 7, 6.5, 5.5, 5.5, 6.7, 4.9, 5.3, 6.7, 5.8, 
6.5, 6, 5.6, 5, 5.5, 6, 6, 6, 3.5, 4.7, 4.5, 5.9, 5, 6, 7, 6, 
5.5, 5, 5.8, 5.5, 5.5, 4.8, 5.7, 6, 7, 5.2, 5, 5.2, 5.3, 5.6, 
5, 5.3, 6, 5, 5.5, 4.5, 5.7, 6, 4.5, 4.4, 5.2, 5.2, 4.1, 5.2, 
5.2, 5.4, 6, 5.5, 6.5, 5, 6, 5.5, 7.5, 5.2, 5.6, 5.4, 5.5, 5, 
5, 6, 5.2, 6, 6.3, 6.3, 4.2, 5.1, 3.5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 5, 
5.6, 5.5, 5, 5, 6, 5.2, 6, 6.3, 6.3, 4.2, 5.1, 3.8, 4, 7, 5, 
6, 4, 5.4, 3.5, 3.6, 5, 6, 4.8, 4.7, 4.4, 5.5, 3.5, 5.3, 4.3, 
5.5, 4.5, 5.5, 4.2, 6, 4.3, 4, 4.7, 3.5, 3.7, 4.2, 5, 5, 5.1, 
5.7, 5, 3.5, 4, 5.6, 3.9, 3.5, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6.5, 5.5, 4.5, 6.5, 
6.5, 3, 5, 5.5, 5.3, 4, 5.5, 6, 4, 5.5, 6, 5, 4, 4.5, 4.5, 4, 
3.5, 4.5, 5, 4, 4.5, 5, 4.7, 6, 3.8, 4.5, 4.1, 4, 3.7, 4, 4.5, 
5, 6, 4.5, 6, 5.7, 3.7, 5.8, 6.2, 5.5, 5, 3.8, 4, 7, 5, 6, 4, 
5.4, 3.5, 3.6, 5, 7, 6.5, 8, 6.5, 5.7, 7.5, 7.3, 7.4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-223L))

Well it works pretty good when i selected only one column, with that code example:

```
data <- aggregate(formula =data1[,2]~data1[,1],
      data = data1,
      FUN = function(e) {b <- shapiro.test(e); c(b$statistic, b$p.value)})
```

but when i used a point to select all my other columns exept my first colum:        `data <- aggregate(formula =.~data1[,1],
          data = data1,
          FUN = function(e) {b <- shapiro.test(e); c(b$statistic, b$p.value)})`

I only got this result:

```
Error in shapiro.test(e) : all 'x' values are identical.
```

Comment: Removed "thanks" message, formatted the error